# IdeaVIM (Rider Vim Plugin) - How to force case insensitive search as the default

Tags: search, vim, case-insensitive, rider, ideavim

I'm using Rider with IdeaVIM. How do I force my default search to be case-insensitive?

In VsVIM, all I had to do was add this to my `.vimrc`

```
set ignorecase
set smartcase
```

But that does not appear to be working for this plugin...

Comment: Seems like IdeaVIM's help files are organized like Vim's. Have you tried going to `:help usr_27`.  I do see this dated sourceforge link, http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/vim/usr_27.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ignorecase` and `smartcase` are [supported](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md) by IdeaVim. You have to put them into ~/.ideavimrc instead of ~/.vimrc, as specified [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#files).

Note that you can also put `source ~/.vimrc` into ~/.ideavimrc to source them.